# how convert [NSData length] to a NSData

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

ex:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; 
int len = [data length];
```

if len = 10000,
i hope i can convert 1000 to a NSData look like

```
char hoperesult[] = {0x10, 0x27, 0x00, 0x00}
```

and hoperesult[] must always 4 Bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the length in 4 little-endian bytes, correct?  I think this will do it:

```
unsigned int len = [data length];
uint32_t little = (uint32_t)NSSwapHostIntToLittle(len);
NSData *byteData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&little length:4];
```

(Note that most network protocols use big-endian, but you showed little-endian so that's what this does.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean here, but I think you are attempting to fill hoperesult with the values found in the file at 'filePath'.

```
struct _hoperesult {
  char data[4];
} *hoperesult;

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSUInteger len = [data length];
NSRange offset;
offset.location = 0;
offset.length = sizeof(_hoperesult);
NSData *hoperesultData;

while( (offset.location + offset.length)  < len ) {
  hoperesultData = [data subdataWithRange:offset];
  // the equivalent of your char hoperesult[] content...
  hoperesult = [hoperesultData bytes]
}
```

An instance of NSData can return a pointer to the actual bytes of data using the "bytes" method. It returns a (const void *).  You could in theory simply cast [data bytes] to a char * and use the offset directly; or you can do like in the above code and return smaller chucks of NSData.

Hope that helps!